# Scala pattern matching with undefined number of parameters

Tags: regex, scala, parsing

I am developping a string parser in scala. I am facing an issue where I need to not always match the same number of parameters.

To be more clear, my code as follow :

```
line match {
  case regex(first, second, third, ...) => // sometimes 2 arguments, sometimes more

        // do stuff

  case _ =>
        println("Wrong parsing")
}
```

As you can see, I need to define dynamically my arguments. Do you have an idea to achieve this ? I tried to use a list, but I had no success.

PS : my regex is dynamically generated

**UPDATE** : thanks to sheunis' answer I found the solution.

```
line match {
  case regex(args @ _*) => 

   println(args(0))
   println(args(1))
   println(args(2))
   ... // as much as you have

  case _ => println("Wrong parsing")

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case class Regex(args: String*)

val test = Regex("a", "b", "c")

test match {
    case Regex(args @ _*) => for (arg <- args) println(arg)

    case _ => println("Wrong parsing")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is actually not working perfectly because, I want to match a String (a log) whereas here it compares an array to an array.